# Events after clickMouseButton

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

In one of my tests I have the mouse moved to a specific location and then `clickMouseButton()` is called. This action is to change the data that is displayed (paging the data.) However, after the click, when I try to get the text in a column of the table to verify that the data changed the data changes back to what was originally displayed and my test fails. My test code is:

```
return Remote
    .moveMouseTo(JE.Buttons.Scrolling(), 5, 100)
    .clickMouseButton()
    .end(Infinity)
    .sleep(500)
    .findByXpath('//*[@id="vwNJEAll_grid_header_tbody"]/tr[2]/td[2]/div')
    .getVisibleText()
    .then(function (result) {
        expect(result).not.to.equal(firstSeenJENumber);
    });
```

The code behind `JE.Buttons.Scrolling()` is:

```
return Remote
    .setFindTimeout(5000)
    .findByXpath('//*[@id="vwNJEAll_grid_table_container"]/div[2]/div');
```

It really seems to me like the locator in Leadfoot is binding to what is on the page when it first loads. Is this the case, and how should I go about getting what I need to happen? I have no other explanation for this, but hopefully you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moveMouseTo` doesn’t accept a Promise as its first argument, so that `moveMouseTo` call is wrong and won’t do what you want. The `JE.Buttons.Scrolling()` call in your example code also occurs immediately (during command chain construction), it doesn’t occur only once `moveMouseTo` is actually performed.

To retrieve and use an element with your abstraction function, pass the function to `then` and then use the element:

```
return Remote
  .then(JE.Buttons.Scrolling)
  .then(function (element) {
    return Remote.moveMouseTo(element, 5, 100);
  })
  // …remainder of test…
```

Comment: Worked like a champ! Thank you very much!