# Leadfoot moveMouseTo requiring X/Y offsets when element is present

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

In the docs for leadfoot Command#moveMouseTo it states that every argument is optional (https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#moveMouseTo). When I pass in an element without passing in X or Y offsets, I get an error about the command requiring the offsets to be present.

```
message: [POST http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/62d8467c-21d9-4565-bc9d-e527c91dc61d/moveto / {}] Missing parameters: element, xoffset, yoffset (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
```

Here's the code in question:

```
.then(function () {
    return contextMenu.Options.Actions.element;
})
.then(function (element) {
    return Remote.moveMouseTo(element);
})
```

contextMenu.Options.Actions.element is defined as:

```
return Remote
    .setFindTimeout(5000)
    .findByXpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]');
```

According to the docs, this should move the mouse to the center of the passed element. Obviously, that isn't happening. Am I doing something the wrong way? Is this not documented correctly, or is this a bug in Leadfoot?

EDIT
The correct format for the test code is:

```
.then(contextMenu.Options.Actions.element)
.then(function (element) {
    return Remote.moveMouseTo(element);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I can see from the information you’ve given here, `contextMenu.Options.Actions.element` is `undefined` or some other type that cannot be serialised to JSON (like `function`).

Comment: If I provide the offset values everything is fine. `return Remote.moveMouseTo(element, 0, 0);` works like a charm.

Comment: Look at the parameters that are being sent to the server in that case. Do they actually include an element, or only xoffset and yoffset?

Comment: Ok, will do, but it might take me a bit to get back to you.

Comment: Actually you might as well just inspect what the type of `element` is when you make the call…

Comment: The value of `typeof element` is function, which seems odd to me. Updating the info in the question to include how `contextMenu.Options.Actions.element` is defined.

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused, because in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099116/events-after-clickmousebutton) you suggested referencing the elements that way and it worked fine as long as I was providing offsets. Now that I am trying something where the offsets are not provided it doesn't work and you're saying that what you suggested I do previously can't be serialised into JSON so it won't work? "Norman, Norman... coordinate."

Comment: Ok, wait... I'm doing something wrong there. Let me fix that and see what comes.

Comment: Ok, changing that reference changes what is passed to moveMouseTo and makes it all work. Not sure why I wrote the test code the wrong way, but fixing it solves the issue. I might also note that I think that because the element was wrong, Intern/Leadfoot was trying its best to move the mouse to where I wanted when I provided offsets, and that is what threw me off.